# Using Mongo-cli to connect to an OpenShift database

Tags: mongodb, shell

I'm trying to connect to a database created onto OpenShift from a cartridge and I'm having issues connecting through it using Mongo client from shell.

I'm using Mac OS Sierra as a client and my Mongo project is hosted onto MiniShift. I can connect locally using OpenShift shell :

`mongo sampledb --host localhost -u user -p password`

But when I try to connect from MacOS directly :

`mongo sampledb --host devmongo-mongo01.192.168.99.100.nip.io -u user -p password`

I got this error stack with verbose mode activated:

```
2017-08-17T18:10:41.938+0200 D NETWORK  [thread1] creating new connection to:devmongo-mongo01.192.168.99.100.nip.io:27017
2017-08-17T18:10:41.941+0200 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-08-17T18:10:41.941+0200 D -        [thread1] User Assertion: 1:couldn't connect to server devmongo-mongo01.192.168.99.100.nip.io:27017, connection attempt failed src/mongo/scripting/mozjs/mongo.cpp 716
2017-08-17T18:10:41.941+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server devmongo-mongo01.192.168.99.100.nip.io:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
2017-08-17T18:10:41.941+0200 D -        [thread1] User Assertion: 12513:connect failed src/mongo/shell/shell_utils.cpp 256
2017-08-17T18:10:41.941+0200 I QUERY    [thread1] MozJS GC prologue heap stats -  total: 3498847 limit: 0
2017-08-17T18:10:41.943+0200 I QUERY    [thread1] MozJS GC epilogue heap stats -  total: 350087 limit: 0
2017-08-17T18:10:41.943+0200 I QUERY    [thread1] MozJS GC prologue heap stats -  total: 241791 limit: 0
2017-08-17T18:10:41.944+0200 I QUERY    [thread1] MozJS GC epilogue heap stats -  total: 50423 limit: 0
2017-08-17T18:10:41.944+0200 D -        [main] User Assertion: 12513:connect failed src/mongo/scripting/mozjs/proxyscope.cpp 295
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: what is the bindip in the Mongo config file? By default it would be localhost, change that to proper ip say 192.168.99.100 and restart mongod. Try connecting again.

Comment: You might be right about the bindip, I've had this issue in the past but on OpenShift this is a bit different, because you use pre-configured cartridge and once deployed, the container are not rootable, which makes the game a bit more complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that it was not possible to edit "bind_ip" after deployment of MongoDB on OpenShift (so not possible to access MongoDB via a tool such a Robomongo). So my solution to use a Mongo Database in an OpenShift project, was to embed the projects that use the DB in same project and using connection String with service to identify the Database container instead of IP because if container is restarted, the IP can be changed but the service will remain the same.